# How to use resource reference into terraform workspace?

Tags: terraform

Currently, I am using terraform workspace to deploy the same code into multiple environments. But in right now I am stuck in referring resource in a specific workspace.

example of code

```
resource "aws_security_group" "testing-ec2" {
  name = "${local.env}-testing-ec2"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  ingress {
    from_port = 8080
    to_port = 8080
    protocol = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${local.security-groups}"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    to_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["${local.bastion_ip}"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = -1
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

workspace security group

```
local {
tf_security-groups = {
   dev = ""
   stg = "${aws_security_group.test-private-alb.id}"
   qa = "${aws_security_group.test1-private-alb.id}"
   prod = "${aws_security_group.test2-private-alb.id}"
 }
 security-groups = "${lookup(local.tf_security-groups,local.env)}"
}
```

when I am trying to apply into stg workspace this error appears

```
* local.tf_security-groups: local.tf_security-groups: Resource 'aws_security_group.test1-private-alb' not found for variable 'aws_security_group.test1-private-alb.id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the data source [`terraform_remote_state`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) to sift through the state but you'd also have to make each of your security group `id`s into outputs.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "this" {
  backend = "s3"

  workspace = "stg"

  config {
    bucket = ""
    key    = ""
    region = ""
  }
}
```

It would be cleaner to use the [`aws_security_group`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/security_group.html) data source instead.

```
locals {
  env = "qa"

  security_group_map = {
    stg  = data.aws_security_group.test_private_alb.id
    qa   = data.aws_security_group.test1_private_alb.id
    prod = data.aws_security_group.test2_private_alb.id
  }

  security_groups = lookup(local.security_group_map, local.env, "")
}

data "aws_security_group" "test_private_alb" {
  name = "test_private_alb"
}

data "aws_security_group" "test1_private_alb" {
  name = "test1_private_alb"
}

data "aws_security_group" "test2_private_alb" {
  name = "test2_private_alb"
}
```